# How to handle .ndf files while restoring backup files in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

am trying to restore db through .bak file while restoring i met this error

[image]

How to avoid this error and do successful restore,

Note: against this Dababase

```
1. one .mdf file Ex: <DBNAME>_Primary01.mdf (Logical Name: FI_Primary)
2. one .ldf file EX: <DBNAME>_Log01.ldf (Logical Name: FI_Log)
3. six .ndf file Ex: <DBNAME>_Data01.ndf (Logical Name: FI_Data)
                 Ex: <DBNAME>_Data_201.ndf(Logical Name: FI_Data_2)
                 Ex: <DBNAME>_Index01.ndf(Logical Name: FI_Index)
                 Ex: <DBNAME>_Index_201.ndf(Logical Name: FI_Index_2)
                 Ex: <DBNAME>_Large01.ndf(Logical Name: FI_Large)
                 Ex: <DBNAME>_Large_Index01.ndf(Logical Name: FI_Large_Index)

RESTORE DATABASE [MESDB] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\MESDB.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'FI_Primary' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MESDB.mdf',  
MOVE N'FI_Data' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MESDB.ndf',  
MOVE N'FI_Index' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MESDB.ndf',  
MOVE N'FI_Data_2' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MESDB.ndf', 
 MOVE N'FI_Index_2' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MESDB.ndf',  
 MOVE N'FI_Large' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MESDB.ndf',  
 MOVE N'FI_Large_Index' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MESDB.ndf',  
 MOVE N'FI_Log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MESDB.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Comment: Click on the Script button on the restore database dialog. This shows both us and you what you are up to when you are restoring your database.

Comment: Hi Olle, i added code in the question portion itself please justify and tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple data files at the same file path (obviously...). `MESDB.ndf` is used for multiple files. Give each file a unique physical path.

Answer (score 2):

You do most likley already have a database file at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MESDB.ndf" and its attached to a running database.

You should remove the existing database, or restore to a new location. I renamed your paths to a directory named DATA2 instead. That should be ok.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MESDB] FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\MESDB.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'FI_Primary' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA2\MESDB.mdf',  
MOVE N'FI_Data' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA2\MESDB.ndf',  
MOVE N'FI_Index' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA2\MESDB.ndf',  
MOVE N'FI_Data_2' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA2\MESDB.ndf', 
MOVE N'FI_Index_2' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA2\MESDB.ndf',  
MOVE N'FI_Large' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA2\MESDB.ndf',  
MOVE N'FI_Large_Index' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA2\MESDB.ndf',  
MOVE N'FI_Log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA2\MESDB.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```